# Apache Spark 2.4: Why is there "No Broadcast"?

Tags: performance, apache-spark, bigdata, broadcast

I have configured spark-submit with

> "--conf",
>                 "spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=536870912",  512MB

But the DAG is still not broadcasting the smaller side of the join.

The code is a simple join. So I'm wondering what is wrong.

The input are files of parquet, stored on S3.

If more information is needed for further analyse, please let me know.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this blog,

> BHJ is not supported for a full outer join. For right outer join, the only left side table can be broadcasted and for other left joins only right table can be broadcasted.

That is the reason the broadcast is not happening.

Comment: I think you forgot to include the blog link.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the configuration *spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold* is overwritten somewhere or is not correctly set. You should check in the Spark UI the *Environment* tab if you find it and check if it's correctly set.
If you just need a quick fix, you can also force the broadcast with the hint *.broadcast* on the Dataset that you already know is small.

Comment: I checked in Spark UI ->Environment and I found spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold 536870912, so I think the configuration is ok. I cannot force broadcast because each side will evaluate according to the input. That is I prefer to set threshold and let spark to make the decision.

Comment: Can you please share your cluster characteristics?

Comment: @CarlosDavidPeña I added configuration in my question. But I think I know the reason.